# C# DateTime Parse is subtracting one day in ISO format

Tags: c#, .net

What is going on that is making my local computer parse a date time differently than another computer. 
As you can see from my screen shot of debugging, the date `5/10/1983` is being parsed into `5/9/1983`, but if I do it in a C# fiddle as you can see at the link, it works fine.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0r2V2q

[image]

Comment: I'd say the likely answer is a timezone difference of 5 hours.

Comment: Still sucks, because it means that ToLocalTime is called AND the time parsed is marked as GTC. While this is correct, it does make debugging code a lot more painfull at times.

Comment: DateTimes/timezones always suck.  This is why we should all have one common timezone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Like the following:

```
string inputStr = "1995-05-10T00:00:00-00:00";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(inputStr,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt);
```